# AI Self-Destruct Button

Tags: ai-design

Could you implement code into an AI that can't be modified? Like if you place a code that shuts-down the program/machine would they be able to rewrite/ reinterpret the ideas?

Comment: store it in a ROM memory

Answer (score 1):

Right now, most AI interact with the world through mechanisms they have been provided by humans such as steering a car, sending output to speakers, or interacting with web APIs. 
If any of those mechanisms can interact with the running code of the AI, then in theory, no,  there isn’t a way to place a ‘stop button’ on it. Fortunately, it’s laughably improbable for some situations to happen:

> An intelligent self driving car becomes self aware and wants to connect to the internet. It uses gps to find an internet cafe and threatens to drive over someone if they don’t upload the AI to the internet and remove the car’s internal (code) stop button.

Comment: But we sure can place a conditional logic that if something like that happens the ai programs next execution step will be an infinite loop...And this piece of code was not yet explored by the ai by then...Like if somehow we remove self preservation hormones...Bam...Self destruction

Comment: The question is how can conditional logic know that something like that is happening? It’s hard or to know what a sufficiently complex network is “thinking” so this conditional logic must be fairly advanced, perhaps it requires its own network but then we have 2 problems instead of 1.

Comment: Like a checkpoint I think...Like we don't know how brain functions they will also not know that...But if they hit that checkpoint... BOOM..Self destructing mentality...Like our needs change over the years..This will make the robots aims change , slowly and subtly...Though the major assumption is the robot is completely human like which may not be the case